# Accessing data from an array when keys have spaces in their names Laravel

Tags: php, arrays, json, api, laravel-5

I am using the Alpha Vantage API and making an external call. the problem is the response returns with numerical values included in the string and was wondering if I could parse this out using laravel 5.2. My controller and view are below along with the json results

```
    array:2 [▼
  "Meta Data" => array:4 [▼
    "1. Information" => "Monthly Adjusted Prices and Volumes"
    "2. Symbol" => "AAPL"
    "3. Last Refreshed" => "2018-04-06"
    "4. Time Zone" => "US/Eastern"
  ]
  "Monthly Adjusted Time Series" => array:219 [▼
    "2018-04-06" => array:7 [▼
      "1. open" => "167.8800"
      "2. high" => "174.2304"
      "3. low" => "164.4700"
      "4. close" => "168.3800"
      "5. adjusted close" => "168.3800"
      "6. volume" => "164408813"
      "7. dividend amount" => "0.0000"
    ]
    "2018-03-29" => array:7 [▼
      "1. open" => "178.5400"
      "2. high" => "183.5000"
      "3. low" => "164.9400"
      "4. close" => "167.7800"
      "5. adjusted close" => "167.7800"
      "6. volume" => "701387082"
      "7. dividend amount" => "0.0000"
    ]
```

The view, This returns an error of "Trying to get property of non-object" I assume this is because of the numerical values and space in front of the objects that I'm trying to declare

```
@foreach($re as $Past)
    <tr>
    @foreach($Past as $key)
            <td>
            {{$key->open}}
            </td>
    @endforeach
    </tr>
@endforeach !>
```

controller, my controller is nothing fancy just a simple API call using Guzzle

```
public function Test(){

        $client = new Client(); //GuzzleHttp\Client
        $promise = $client->get('https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_MONTHLY_ADJUSTED&symbol=AAPL&apikey=DEMOKey');
        $body = $promise->getbody();
        $result = json_decode($body, true);
         return view('pages.test', ['re' => $result]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your issue lies here [Eloquent: Serialization](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-serialization#hiding-attributes-from-json)

In your model(s) add this line

```
$hidden = ['field1', 'field2'];
```

These fields are now hidden from json replies.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't believe my title was clear enough and have made the corrections.